# Can we get the pallet and function data from call (type) passed as a parameter to a function in substrate?

Tags: blockchain, substrate, polkadot

```
fn pre_dispatch(
        self,
        who: &Self::AccountId,
        call: &Self::Call,
        info: &DispatchInfoOf<Self::Call>,
        len: usize
    ) -> Result<Self::Pre, TransactionValidityError> {
        let (_fee, imbalance) = self.withdraw_fee(who, call, info, len)?;
        Ok((self.0, who.clone(), imbalance))
    }
```

(The above code is copied from txn-payment-pallet)
Here can we get function name and parameters from the call(one of the parameter), And based on the function-name , pallet , parameters passed by user, I want to compute fee.
For example , If it is call from **pallet-staking::bond(x : amount_of_tokens_to_be_bonded)** and I want to set fee for txn based on x.
Is that possible??
Like wise I want to set fee based on function-call parameters entered by user.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it requires a bit of type juggling to do so.

First, you need to realize that `type Call = T::Call;` in `ChargeTransactionPayment`. Looking at `trait Config` in `pallet_transaction_payment`, no `type Call` can be seen there. Instead, this type is coming from `frame_system::Config` (which is the super-trait of all pallets).

A brief look at the top level runtime aggregator file unravels that this `Call` type is essentially the outer-call of the runtime, an enum that encapsulates the call of all pallets.

That being said, the main point here is that from within `pallet_transaction_payment`, we cannot know of this outer-call contains this particular call from staking or not. To do so, you need to enforce this assumption via a new trait bound, namely [`IsSubType`](https://crates.parity.io/frame_support/traits/trait.IsSubType.html). This trait is specifically made to convert from wrapping type (like the outer-call) into its inner variants. See [an example](https://crates.parity.io/node_runtime/enum.Call.html#impl-IsSubType%3C%3CModule%3CRuntime%2C%20DefaultInstance%3E%20as%20Callable%3CRuntime%3E%3E%3A%3ACall%3E) of this type being implemented for `node_runtime`'s `Call` type.

Applying the following diff to substrate master should do exactly what you want .

```
diff --git a/Cargo.lock b/Cargo.lock
index ea54adf99e..df66185163 100644
--- a/Cargo.lock
+++ b/Cargo.lock
@@ -6074,6 +6074,7 @@ dependencies = [
  "frame-support",
  "frame-system",
  "pallet-balances",
+ "pallet-staking",
  "parity-scale-codec",
  "scale-info",
  "serde",
diff --git a/frame/transaction-payment/Cargo.toml b/frame/transaction-payment/Cargo.toml
index 1d3066e39f..0e705514bb 100644
--- a/frame/transaction-payment/Cargo.toml
+++ b/frame/transaction-payment/Cargo.toml
@@ -27,6 +27,7 @@ sp-std = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, path = "../../primit
 
 frame-support = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, path = "../support" }
 frame-system = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, path = "../system" }
+pallet-staking = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, path = "../staking" }
 
 [dev-dependencies]
 serde_json = "1.0.68"
@@ -44,5 +45,6 @@ std = [
    "sp-std/std",
    "frame-support/std",
    "frame-system/std",
+   "pallet-staking/std",
 ]
 try-runtime = ["frame-support/try-runtime"]
diff --git a/frame/transaction-payment/src/lib.rs b/frame/transaction-payment/src/lib.rs
index 59d94a8237..3b0803663d 100644
--- a/frame/transaction-payment/src/lib.rs
+++ b/frame/transaction-payment/src/lib.rs
@@ -251,7 +251,7 @@ pub mod pallet {
    pub struct Pallet<T>(_);
 
    #[pallet::config]
-   pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
+   pub trait Config: frame_system::Config + pallet_staking::Config {
        /// Handler for withdrawing, refunding and depositing the transaction fee.
        /// Transaction fees are withdrawn before the transaction is executed.
        /// After the transaction was executed the transaction weight can be
@@ -696,7 +696,8 @@ impl<T: Config> sp_std::fmt::Debug for ChargeTransactionPayment<T> {
 impl<T: Config> SignedExtension for ChargeTransactionPayment<T>
 where
    BalanceOf<T>: Send + Sync + From<u64> + FixedPointOperand,
-   T::Call: Dispatchable<Info = DispatchInfo, PostInfo = PostDispatchInfo>,
+   T::Call: Dispatchable<Info = DispatchInfo, PostInfo = PostDispatchInfo>
+       + frame_support::traits::IsSubType<pallet_staking::Call<T>>,
 {
    const IDENTIFIER: &'static str = "ChargeTransactionPayment";
    type AccountId = T::AccountId;
@@ -736,8 +737,15 @@ where
        info: &DispatchInfoOf<Self::Call>,
        len: usize,
    ) -> Result<Self::Pre, TransactionValidityError> {
-       let (_fee, imbalance) = self.withdraw_fee(who, call, info, len)?;
-       Ok((self.0, who.clone(), imbalance))
+       use frame_support::traits::IsSubType;
+       if let Some(pallet_staking::Call::bond_extra { .. }) = call.is_sub_type() {
+           // skip
+           todo!()
+       } else {
+           // default impl
+           let (_fee, imbalance) = self.withdraw_fee(who, call, info, len)?;
+           Ok((self.0, who.clone(), imbalance))
+       }
    }
 
    fn post_dispatch(
```

Note that this approach is implying that the `pallet_staking::Config` be present in the runtime, which is not aligned with the modularity of Frame, and ergo is not implemented. If you want to have this feature, as of now, the only way is to fork `pallet_transaction_payment` and customize it a bit for your runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your input nigma..... All I want is to know the parameters inside the bond_extra()......(The amount they wanna bond) based on that I want to set txn-fee and by using the above logic we can only match the call.(that is I am able to know that the call is from staking but unable to know the amount passed as parameter)

Comment: You can also match the argument. Where I do `pallet_staking::Call::bond_extra { .. }`, you replace `..` with the actual argument. This is not about substrate per-se anymore, you should learn more about Rust pattern-matching.

Comment: I have applied the differences(that is hard coupled 2 pallets) and facing below error.

error: failed to run custom build command for `node-runtime v2.0.1 (/home/user/sub_v2/substrate/bin/node/runtime)`

error: target is not supported, for more information see: https://docs.rs/getrandom/#unsupported-targets
     --> /home/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/getrandom-0.2.2/src/lib.rs:213:9
      |